# If I write a class transformer for a project licensed under CC BY-NC-ND, may I distribute that transformer?

Tags: creative-commons, java, cc-by-nc-nd

If I write a Java class transformer that transforms code from a project licensed under CC BY-NC-ND, is that legal?

I am not actually distributing a modified copy of the project, but while a specific class of that project is loading, I transform part of that dynamically at runtime. Is this legal or a violation of the license?

Comment: Privately transforming the work is not a violation: the ND provision in 4.0 says "you may... produce and reproduce, but not Share, Adapted Material" so the *use* of such a transformer is not a violation. I am concerned, however, that such a transformer might itself be a derivative of the work it is designed to transform, in which case distributing it would be a violation. (I don't have an answer for you whether it is or not.)

Comment: You would be violating the spirit if not the letter IMHO. Which a judge may or may not consider OK.